# how to execute procedure with multiply arguement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create proc [dbo].[SSRproc] (
    @StartDate Date
    ,@EndDate Date
    ,@DepartmentGroupKey int
)
as begin
select F.Date,
    F.AccountKey,
    F.Amount,
    F.OrganizationKey,
    O.OrganizationName,
    F.DepartmentGroupKey,
    D.DepartmentGroupName
from [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[FactFinance] as f
inner join dbo.DimOrganization as O on F.OrganizationKey = O.OrganizationKey
inner join dbo.DimDepartmentGroup as D on F.DepartmentGroupKey = D.DepartmentGroupKey
where F.Date between @StartDate and @EndDate and @DepartmentGroupKey = F.DepartmentGroupKey
end

[dbo].[SSRproc] '2010-12-29', '2011-01-29', (3,5)
```

here is my procedure code and at the end I have execution but I need DepartmentGroupKey has multiply argument like key will be (3,5) or (3,8,9) and like that what I have to do?

Comment: With the inclusion of the `dbo` schema, this looks to be SQL Server *not* MySQL.

Comment: Seems like `@DepartmentGroupKey` should be a table type parameter.

Comment: @Larnu can U give me query? what will I change?

Comment: See [Use Table-Valued Parameters (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

If your Procedure is called from where a Table Valued Parameter is supported that would be the best solution. But if your Procedure is called from somewhere else this is not always possible so here is a alternative.

```
create proc [dbo].[SSRproc] (
@StartDate Date
,@EndDate Date
,@DepartmentGroupKey varchar(10)
 )
 as begin .....
 .....and F.DepartmentGroupKey in (select value from STRING_SPLIT(@DepartmentGroupKey)
```

And then the execute:

```
execute dbo.SSRproc
  @DepartmentGroupKey = '3,5'
```